# Loading custom class in CakePHP3

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

I am trying to load a custom class in my CakePHP3 project, although I can't seem to find out what I am missing.

I have a folder `src/Library` with `Config.php` in it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Library;

/**
 * Class containing CONST values for important settings
 *
 * @version 1.0
 * @author berry
 */
class Config
{
    const UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = './upload/';
}
```

I put `use App\Library\Config;` in my `PicturesController`, which Visual Studio even recognizes as a valid class (I can access the `const` through intellisense)

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Filesystem\Folder;
use Cake\Filesystem\File;
use App\Library\Config;

/**
 * Pictures Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\PicturesTable $Pictures
 */
class PicturesController extends AppController
{
    public function upload()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            $oConfig = new Config();

            $oUploadDir = new Folder($oConfig::UPLOAD_DIRECTORY);

            debug($oUploadDir);

            $aFile = $this->request->data('submittedfile');
        }

    }
```

So despite my IDE even registering the class (and telling me I'm using it correctly) I get `Class 'App\Library\Config' not found` thrown in the browser.

Comment: Your class belongs in the vendor directory. There is a great explaination here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518238/how-can-i-use-my-own-external-class-in-cakephp-3-0

Comment: Is the Config.php file have correct permissions?

Comment: Well, I changed the foldername from Library to my name, and it worked. So either the Lirary folder didn't have the right permissions, or Library is already in use.

Comment: @BerryM. try providing decent answers to questions to gain rep instead of suggesting petty updates to existing good answers. (I note none of your answers have votes to date) Regards.

Comment: @RachelGallen such criticism, while I admit is justified, does as far as I am aware not belong in a comment section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name from Library to Berry (My first name).

Apparently you can't call it Library. Probably used somewhere else in Cake.