# Cakephp use component out side controller folder

Tags: cakephp, components

I am using cakephp 2.9 version. I have created custom folder "test" out side controller directory with test.php file. I want to load component in cakephp.
I have tried to load using but it's giving me errors.

use Cake\Core\App;
App::uses('DataImport', 'Controller/Component');

Please suggest if anyone knows.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are breaking the CakePHP MVC principals

I encourage you to take a look at that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518238/how-can-i-use-my-own-external-class-in-cakephp-3-0)